# Which Swing layout manager should I use?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I am creating a Swing dialog window like below:

[image]

The `header` and `footer` areas have fixed size.  The `area 1 and 2`'s size are not fixed. They can have several lines of content and the line number can increase `at runtime`.

And in future, I may need to add `area 3`.

How should I use Swing layout managers to achieve this UI?

### ADD 1

The area 1 and 2 are independent of each other.

In each of them, I want to place several panels vertically. Each panel hold a line of string. The panel number can vary at runtime.

Comment: `BorderLayout` and `GridLayout`, `BorderLayout` and `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `BorderLayout` for the main layout.

1. add the "header" to the `NORTH`.
2. add the "footer" to the `SOUTH`.
3. Create another panel and add it to the `CENTER`. Then set the layout manager of this panel to an appropriate layout manager. We can't advise you what layout manager to use for this panel since we don't know how the two components area related. Then add "area1" and "area2" to this panel.

The key to this answer is that you don't need to use a single layout manager, you can nest panels with different layout managers.

Comment: The area 1 and 2 are independent of each other.

Comment: @smwikipedia, yes but we don't know how they should resize as the size of the window changes. Do then need to scroll? Do they have a maximum size etc... So you need to choose the layout manager that will size the components as required. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You could use a GridBagLayout, BoxLayout, GridLayout, SpringLayout. GroupLayout, SpringLayout. Learn how each works and choose which one you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a `BorderLayout` for this one:

- `header` in `PAGE_START`
- `footer` in `PAGE_END`
- `area1` & `area2` (each in a `JScrollPane`) in a `JSplitPane` in the `CENTER`

Comment: `JSplitPane` only split 2 components.  But I may need an `area 3` in future.

Comment: *"But I may need an area 3 in future"*  Well given that we don't have access to a crystal ball, doesn't it make sense to ***specify that in the question?***

Comment: *"Each panel hold a line of string."*  Get rid of the panels and use a `JList` instead.