# How to move a imageIcon on the left side of JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, imageicon

I'm trying to move `ImageIcon torrentIcon` to the left side of `JPanel jp`, because it's located in the center of panel near the `JLabel jl`. Neither `setBounds()` nor `setHorizontalTextPosition()`, `setVerticalTextPosition()` methods didn't help with that. I also tried making it by adding `torrenIcon` to another `imageL JLabel` and moving by `setLocation()`, but it didn`t work too. What should I do then?

This is a code part of creating panel:

```
private static JPanel setPanel() {
    JLabel jl = new JLabel("Авторизуйтесь на сумнівний сайт");
    jl.setForeground(Color.white);
    jl.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 40));

    ImageIcon torrentIcon = new ImageIcon("Icon.png");
    Image im = torrentIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    torrentIcon = new ImageIcon(im);

    JLabel imageL = new JLabel();
    imageL.setIcon(torrentIcon);
    imageL.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    imageL.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    jl.setHorizontalTextPosition(0);
    jl.setVerticalTextPosition(0);
    
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    p.setBackground(Color.RED);
    p.add(imageL);
    p.add(jl);

    return p;
}
```

Comment: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Swing layout manager should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382290/which-swing-layout-manager-should-i-use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code and created the following GUI.

[image: Example]

Don't use `static` methods with Swing.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

When you type:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

the default is a `FlowLayout`.  The Swing components will "flow" from left to right.

Here's the same statement with all of the default values explicitly defined.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
```

I read the icon from a URL, so anyone can run this code and get the same result.

Here's the complete runnable code.  Save this so you can easily test different `JPanels`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LayoutExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LayoutExample());
    }

    private Image image;

    public LayoutExample() {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://vectorified.com/images/torrent-icon-27.png");
            this.image = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Авторизуйтесь на сумнівний сайт");
        jl.setForeground(Color.white);
        jl.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 40));

        Image im = image.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon torrentIcon = new ImageIcon(im);

        JLabel imageL = new JLabel();
        imageL.setIcon(torrentIcon);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        p.setBackground(Color.RED);
        p.add(imageL);
        p.add(jl);

        return p;
    }

}
```

Comment: Since Java 7, there is [multi-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html). In any case [MalformedURLException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html) is a subclass of `java.io.IOException` so no need for separate `catch` blocks - especially since each one does the same, exact thing, i.e. prints the stack trace only. I am referring to `LayoutExample` class constructor.